# Socket.io "failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

There are other posts asking the same question but my situation is different. The code works but with the error "**failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response**" displayed in Chrome console. I tried to strip  all the code and came up with a very slimmed down code which continues to give the error. Here is the test case:

**Server side:**

```
 var http    = require('http');
 var express = require('express');

 app    = express();
 server = http.createServer(app);
 serveFile = function (req,res) { 
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket.html');
              };  
 io = require('socket.io')(server);
 io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket) {
   socket.on('from_client',function(data) { console.log(data.name); }); 
   socket.emit('dateFromServer', {'date': new Date()});
 }); 
 app.use(serveFile);
 io.listen(server);
 server.listen(2000);
```

**Client side: (the socket.html file)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
      socket.on('dateFromServer', function(data){
        $('#date').text(data.date);
      });
      socket.emit('from_client',{'name':'John'});
    </script>
    <div id="date">Date will be displayed here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

~
Please, can someone explain what is causing the error? The messages are sent/received, from the client/server, as expected.
~